# How do I set auto increment starting at 5000

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have 67,828 records in my current database without `Primary Key & AUTO_INCREMENT`

Now I want add one column name `ID` as primary key, AUTO_INCREMENT and starting with number `5000`.

Current DB

```
Name Email
--------------------
John  john@doe.com
Peter peter@john.com
```

New format should be

```
ID   Name Email
--------------------
5000 John  john@doe.com
5001 Peter peter@john.com
```

Let me know.

Comment: search Google before add SO there are so many example there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one -

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD COLUMN id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST,
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (id),
  AUTO_INCREMENT = 5000;
```

Answer (score 3):

To start with an AUTO_INCREMENT value other than 1, you can set that value with CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE, like this:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 5000;
```

Answer (score 2):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this query for MySQL

ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT =2000

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, the SQL to do this is something like

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD ID INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, ADD INDEX (ID);
ALTER TABLE table AUTO_INCREMENT = 5000;
```